restart http server if input file has been changed
I have an application that runs on Kubernetes to measure storage performance. Upon completion, it writes statistics in terms of IOPS, Bandwidth, and Latency to the fio-summary.txt file. Afterward, I push the metrics to Prometheus using the following Python code. While I can see the metrics on Prometheus, they are not updating even after the fio-summary.txt file has been changed. How can we continuously monitor the fio-summary.txt file for changes and reload metrics accordingly?
I'm sharing fio-summary.txt and python script here.
# cat fio-summary.txt
RAND_IOPS_READ,RAND_IOPS_WRITE,MIX_IOPS_READ,MIX_IOPS_WRITE,RAND_BW_READ,RAND_BW_WRITE,SEQ_BW_READ,SEQ_BW_WRITE,AVG_LATENCY_READ,AVG_LATENCY_WRITE
[9999.0, 8393.5, 2266.0, 756.0, 304.0, 32.8, 311.5, 0.605, 1.655, 15.235]
[84935.0, 8158.5, 1375.5, 448.5, 332.5, 32.75, 1156.5, 7.596, 30.105, 309.343]
[83126.0, 6711.5, 1668.0, 551.0, 326.0, 27.6, 1081.5, 16.85, 61.481, 752.128]

Please find the Python code here
import re
import time
from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, Gauge
from prometheus_client.exposition import generate_latest
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.events import FileModifiedEvent
import threading


# Define a registry to hold your metrics
registry = CollectorRegistry()

# Function to create gauge metrics for different thread counts and metric types
def create_gauge_metrics(thread_counts, metric_types):
    gauge_metrics = {}
    for metric_type in metric_types:
        for count in thread_counts:
            gauge_metrics[f'FIO_{metric_type}_threadCount_{count}'] = Gauge(f'FIO_{metric_type}_threadCount_{count}', f'FIO_{metric_type.capitalize()} for {count} Threads', registry=registry)
    return gauge_metrics

# Example thread counts and metric types
thread_counts = [1, 20, 40]
metric_types = ['RAND_IOPS_READ', 'RAND_IOPS_WRITE', 'MIX_IOPS_READ', 'MIX_IOPS_WRITE', 'RAND_BW_READ', 'RAND_BW_WRITE', 'SEQ_BW_READ', 'SEQ_BW_WRITE', 'AVG_LATENCY_READ', 'AVG_LATENCY_WRITE']

# Create gauge metrics
gauge_metrics = create_gauge_metrics(thread_counts, metric_types)

def transpose_data(filename):
    transposed_data = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        headers = file.readline().strip().split(',')
        for line in file:
            #values = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', line)[0].split(', ')             Working for Windows
            values = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', line.strip())[0].split(', ')      # for Linux
            transposed_data.append(values)
    return list(zip(*transposed_data)), headers


def expose_data_from_file(filename, gauge_metrics):
    print("Exposing data from file:", filename)
    data, headers = transpose_data(filename)
    print("Data read from file:", data)
    print("Headers:", headers)
    for metric_type, values in zip(headers, data):
        for count, value in enumerate(values):
            metric_name = f'FIO_{metric_type}_threadCount_{thread_counts[count]}'
            try:
                thread_value = float(value)
                print("Setting metric:", metric_name, "to value:", thread_value)
                gauge_metrics[metric_name].set(thread_value)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing value {value} for metric {metric_name}: {e}")





# Example usage
expose_data_from_file('fio-summary.txt', gauge_metrics)

class FileEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, FileModifiedEvent) and event.src_path == 'fio-summary.txt':
            print("File modified! Reloading metrics...")
            expose_data_from_file('fio-summary.txt', gauge_metrics)
        else:
            print("Event type:", type(event))



# MetricsHandler class
class MetricsHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print("HTTP GET request received")
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(generate_latest(registry))
        print("HTTP response sent")


# Expose the registry containing your metrics
def start_http_server():
    print("Starting HTTP server...")
    server_address = ('', 8080)  # Change port if needed
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MetricsHandler)
    print('Serving metrics on port 8080')
    httpd.serve_forever()


# File change handler
def start_monitoring():
    # Create an event handler
    event_handler = FileEventHandler()

    # Create an observer
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, '.', recursive=False)  # Monitor only current directory

    # Start the observer
    observer.start()

    # Start the HTTP server in a separate thread
    http_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_http_server)
    http_thread.start()

    try:
        # Keep the observer running indefinitely
        observer.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_monitoring()


Please find the output after running python script. Note that fio-summary.txt file has modified and watchdog was updated. We can see this in the output
# python3.6 17.py
Exposing data from file: fio-summary.txt
Data read from file: [('999.0', '84935.0', '83126.0'), ('8393.5', '8158.5', '6711.5'), ('2266.0', '1375.5', '1668.0'), ('756.0', '448.5', '551.0'), ('304.0', '332.5', '326.0'), ('32.8', '32.75', '27.6'), ('311.5', '1156.5', '1081.5'), ('0.605', '7.596', '16.85'), ('1.655', '30.105', '61.481'), ('15.235', '309.343', '752.128')]
Headers: ['RAND_IOPS_READ', 'RAND_IOPS_WRITE', 'MIX_IOPS_READ', 'MIX_IOPS_WRITE', 'RAND_BW_READ', 'RAND_BW_WRITE', 'SEQ_BW_READ', 'SEQ_BW_WRITE', 'AVG_LATENCY_READ', 'AVG_LATENCY_WRITE']
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_IOPS_READ_threadCount_1 to value: 999.0
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_IOPS_READ_threadCount_20 to value: 84935.0
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_IOPS_READ_threadCount_40 to value: 83126.0
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_IOPS_WRITE_threadCount_1 to value: 8393.5
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_IOPS_WRITE_threadCount_20 to value: 8158.5
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_IOPS_WRITE_threadCount_40 to value: 6711.5
Setting metric: FIO_MIX_IOPS_READ_threadCount_1 to value: 2266.0
Setting metric: FIO_MIX_IOPS_READ_threadCount_20 to value: 1375.5
Setting metric: FIO_MIX_IOPS_READ_threadCount_40 to value: 1668.0
Setting metric: FIO_MIX_IOPS_WRITE_threadCount_1 to value: 756.0
Setting metric: FIO_MIX_IOPS_WRITE_threadCount_20 to value: 448.5
Setting metric: FIO_MIX_IOPS_WRITE_threadCount_40 to value: 551.0
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_BW_READ_threadCount_1 to value: 304.0
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_BW_READ_threadCount_20 to value: 332.5
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_BW_READ_threadCount_40 to value: 326.0
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_BW_WRITE_threadCount_1 to value: 32.8
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_BW_WRITE_threadCount_20 to value: 32.75
Setting metric: FIO_RAND_BW_WRITE_threadCount_40 to value: 27.6
Setting metric: FIO_SEQ_BW_READ_threadCount_1 to value: 311.5
Setting metric: FIO_SEQ_BW_READ_threadCount_20 to value: 1156.5
Setting metric: FIO_SEQ_BW_READ_threadCount_40 to value: 1081.5
Setting metric: FIO_SEQ_BW_WRITE_threadCount_1 to value: 0.605
Setting metric: FIO_SEQ_BW_WRITE_threadCount_20 to value: 7.596
Setting metric: FIO_SEQ_BW_WRITE_threadCount_40 to value: 16.85
Setting metric: FIO_AVG_LATENCY_READ_threadCount_1 to value: 1.655
Setting metric: FIO_AVG_LATENCY_READ_threadCount_20 to value: 30.105
Setting metric: FIO_AVG_LATENCY_READ_threadCount_40 to value: 61.481
Setting metric: FIO_AVG_LATENCY_WRITE_threadCount_1 to value: 15.235
Setting metric: FIO_AVG_LATENCY_WRITE_threadCount_20 to value: 309.343
Setting metric: FIO_AVG_LATENCY_WRITE_threadCount_40 to value: 752.128
Starting HTTP server...
Serving metrics on port 8080
HTTP GET request received
192.168.56.1 - - [08/Apr/2024 05:42:27] "GET /metrics HTTP/1.1" 200 -
HTTP response sent
HTTP GET request received
192.168.56.1 - - [08/Apr/2024 05:42:27] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
HTTP response sent
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.FileModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
Event type: <class 'watchdog.events.DirModifiedEvent'>
HTTP GET request received
192.168.56.1 - - [08/Apr/2024 05:42:44] "GET /metrics HTTP/1.1" 200 -
HTTP response sent
HTTP GET request received
192.168.56.1 - - [08/Apr/2024 05:42:44] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
HTTP response sent

Please help me.
I have tried with watchdog, still not working

What exactly is not working? Show us your output.

Hi @KlausD.
Values are not updating when we refresh the page at http://IP:8080/metrics in the browser. Despite changing the file content, the latest results are not displayed upon page refresh. Instead, old values persist.

You don't want to show us the output of the print() calls?

Looks like event.src_path is not what you check for.

It appears that the control is entering the else block even when the file has been changed.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
